# unordered list navigation html structure

Tags: html, css, navigation, html-lists

I'm a novice and ran my code through an html validator.

Regarding my navigation I receive a message that reads: :Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context"

Here is the html structure:

```
<nav>
<div class="nav_container">
<ul class="navigation">

 <ul class="logo">
    <li><a href="index.htm"><img src="images/rh_logo_v5.png" alt="roundhaus logo"/></a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href="index.htm">home</a></li>
   </ul>
<ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href="reclaimedwood.htm">reclaimed wood</a></li>
       <li><a href="design.htm">design</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href="flooring.htm">flooring</a></li>
    <li><a href="paneling.htm">paneling</a></li>
    <li><a href="beams.htm">beams</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href="shelving.htm">shelving</a>
    </li><li><a href="mantels.htm">mantels</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href="news.htm">news</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="subnav">
    <li><a href="woodtypes.htm">wood types</a></li>
    <li><a href="phrases.htm">phrases</a></li>
</ul>

</ul>
</div>
</nav>
```

Whats wrong with it? It looks fine across browsers. Should I be concerned or take action?

Comment: Wrap the inner unordered lists inside `li` tags. Edit: Yaron beat me to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A ul can not be a direct child of another ul, it needs to be contained within an li

```
<ul class="navigation">
  <li>
    <ul class="logo">
      <li><a href="index.htm"><img src="images/rh_logo_v5.png" alt="roundhaus logo"/></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="index.htm">home</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="reclaimedwood.htm">reclaimed wood</a></li>
      <li><a href="design.htm">design</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="flooring.htm">flooring</a></li>
      <li><a href="paneling.htm">paneling</a></li>
      <li><a href="beams.htm">beams</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="shelving.htm">shelving</a></li>
      <li><a href="mantels.htm">mantels</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="news.htm">news</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="woodtypes.htm">wood types</a></li>
      <li><a href="phrases.htm">phrases</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

you could also give the menu some headings by adding it in the li before the child ul,

Answer (score 7):

you must wrap each of the inner ul with an li

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
           <li>...</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your structure is likely wrong. Logo is not a list or list-item. As well as list item that contains *just* another list is generally pointless.

Use heading element for logo (I usually use `H1` for home page and `H3` with link inside it for other pages):

```
<!-- for home page -->
<h1 id="logo">Company</h1>

<!-- for other pages -->
<h3 id="logo"><a href="/">Company</a></h3>
```

And make sure that your navigation has correct hierarchy like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Desktops</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Laptops</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tablets</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In the example, each `LI` has its own link and subsections of section that the link represents, and thus the link text is heading for subsections' list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap

```
<ul class="navigation">
 <ul class="logo">
```

as

```
<ul class="navigation">
   <li>
    <ul class="logo">
     ...
    </ul>
  </li>
```

and so on...